# SSRS Multiple Sorts in one Matrix in One column

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

This is a follow on question from one I have earlier posted but have not reviewed the answers for and I didnt want to confuse things.  Can someone tell me if this is possible.  I have 2 columns, Company and revenue, I want to initially sort by revenue "desc" but when Company equals Other I want to set this to be last in the order by despite whatever the revenue value is?

Thanks again for all the help I receive on here. P

I want my data to look like the following

> Company Name      Revenue
>   ACE                    £3
>   Something              £2
>   Another N              £1
>   Other                  £6

So its ordered by revenue but Company Name "Other" will always be the last entry despite what the Revenue value is.  Thanks

Comment: can you post sample data and expect result ?

Comment: Hi Chanom, thanks for the reply it should look something like this

Comment: Didn't you try use CASE statement in sql like this 
      ORDER BY CASE 
   WHEN CompanyName = 'Other' THEN -1 
   ELSE Revenue
  END DESC

Answer (score 0):

After many ways of trying to do this I managed to find the way that suited my needs best, I created a second column within my Matrix listing the Revenue, but when the Company Name = Other I set this to 1, then ordered my table based on the newly created column, then hid it and only showed the column with the Revenues in it, this forced Other to appear at the bottom.  Thankfully none of the other companies will ever have a revenue of 1 or less so will never break my sort order.  Hope this explanation helps someone else.